# Swift Segmented Control default state

Tags: swift, swift2, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a segmented control that works lovely if you tap one of the segments BUT if you don't tap anything and let it sit at the natural resting spot which is the first segment it doesnt work

I tested this by tapping another segment and continuing the app and it worked, and i also tested by tapping another segment and then going back to the first segment and it worked

```
@IBAction func segmentedControl(sender: UISegmentedControl) {

    switch segmenControl.selectedSegmentIndex {

    case 0:
        numberOfParticipants = "4"
    case 1:
        numberOfParticipants = "6"
    case 2:
        numberOfParticipants = "8"
    case 3:
        numberOfParticipants = "10"
    case 4:
        numberOfParticipants = "12"
    case 5:
        numberOfParticipants = "14"
    case 6:
        numberOfParticipants = "16"
    default:
        break
    }


}
```

It makes sense since it is wrapped in an IBAction and nothing is being pressed therefore it's not being triggered. How do i fix this issue?

**Edit**

By doesn't work i mean if the segment that is highlighted says 4 AND the user taps a continue button (different button) then a variable gets updated with a string of "4" and then firebase gets updated to say x = 4

So what is happening is when you land on the page by default the 4 segment is highlighted and if you want 4 to be your option you would leave it alone and hit the continue button...my problem is that if you don't interact with the segment control and actually tap 4 then the code never gets run, but if you tapped 6 then back to 4 it would trigger

Comment: What issue? As you said yourself, if the user doesn't tap anything, nothing happens. What's the problem? (I'm not being snippy; I really don't understand. The phrase "if you don't tap anything and let it sit at the natural resting spot which is the first segment it doesnt work" communicates nothing to my mind; what would "work" _mean_ here?)

Comment: i have updated my question...basically depending on what segment is highlighted when you hit the continue button code is sent to firebase...since no interaction is being done to the segment if you want the default value to be 4 the code doesn't get run ...i hope that clears it up

Comment: Looks like you need is to define a default value to the numberOfParticipants  in case no tab is pressed

Answer (score 3):

Your questions in not very clear in defining what exactly seems to be broken. What doesn't work if you don't tap it? In general there are 2 steps involved in using UISegmentedControls. In step 1 you set it in your initialization - i.e. viewDidLoad - via:

```
segmenControl.selectedSegmentIndex =  your_initial_value
```

Of course your initial value cannot be numberOfParticipants because the control only has 6 values..

Then step 2 is something like your IBAction which looks fine. Your use of magic numbers is of course a bit problematic.

Comment: what do you mean when you say magic numbers?  I have updated my question

Comment: Yeah - I saw and am baffled :] You did not mention any continue buttons, firebase or any of that in your original question. In any case it looks like you rely on your segmented control to initialize things. But it should be the other way around. You should have a default to which you initialize your segmented control and that value should also govern the other parts of your code that don't currently work. BTW: Magic number refers to direct usage of a number in code.

Comment: Never knew initialization will cause such a headache. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This is how I understand the question:
You have a "Continue" button and if you hit it, you want it to reflect the state of the segmented control. Correct?

If that's the case, you don't need the IBAction, just read `segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex` directly in IBAction of the Continue button.

Answer (score 0):

I understand your question and had the same problem myself.
I experimented as I did not want any Segment in my Segmented Control to be highlighted or selected at all as this would cause confusion to my users and if the highlighted start index was actually what the User required,then when pressed did not perform the Action within the Switch Case area.
So...  I made the Index Value -1 and this does not highlight any part of the Segment at all, it works a treat for my requirements and makes the user select the desired segment.

I set this up within my ViewDidLoad()

```
mySegmentedControlOutlet.selectedSegmentIndex = -1
```